# log4j-over-slf4j missing class org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender logback

Tags: class, log4j, slf4j, logback

We are using a 3rd-party jar that contains a dependency to the log4j.varia.NullAppender class.   We are transitioning to logback, but unable to change the 3rd-party jar, so we plan to use the log4j-over-sl4j bridge for now with the rest of our code still using the existing log4j calls.

Since the log4j-over-slf4j jar does not contain the NullAppender class, what is the best way to spoof it?  Should we write our own and put it on the class path?  Should we augment the log4j-over-slf4j bridge jar with this class?

What have others done who have run into this and does the logback project plan to support backwards compatibility?  This is a real hassle for those of us who want to migrate when existing jar files use log4j classes that are not in the bridge.

Any suggestions or best practices?

Comment: turns out it is worse than this, we just discovered they are using the addApenders method on the Logger class.  It appears we may not be able to move to logback :-(